# Using source() in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to `source()` several R scripts using a for loop, as such:

```
script_list <- list("script1.R", "script2.R", "script3.R")

for (i in 1:length(script_list)){
  try(source(script_list[[i]]))
}
```

However, I often find that some of the scripts have not been sourced. I therefore have two related questions: a) what errors in earlier scripts could prevent execution of later scripts? b) what function/code would allow for all of the scripts to be executed, regardless of errors in earlier scripts?

Comment: Can you make this example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by giving specific (minimal) examples of script files such that you don't get the behavior you expect?

Comment: Try removing the `try()` and your loop will halt if one of the scripts contains an error. Also you can use the simpler `script_list <- c("script1.R", ...)` and then iterate over that vector with `for (f in script_list)`.

Comment: How about lapply? Like this: `lapply(script_list, function(x) try(source(x)))`

Comment: @Antti: At the Hadley Wickham Master R workshop I was told that `lapply()` doesn't necessarily execute the functions in the order specified, and therefore a for loop would be better.

Comment: @histelheim: I didn't know that. I need to be careful in the future then.